# How to use karate.get in Java with Karate Framework?

Tags: karate

in javascript I use `karate.get('key')` but how to use this feature in Java please?

Comment: I honestly think you are trying to do too much in karate or using it the wrong way:|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not supported.

What teams typically do is pass the data they need to the Java side via function arguments.